# Reference a long-forgoten account

Tags: merkle-patricia-tries, protocol, state-trie, state-trie-pruning

In the [Etherem Blog](https://blog.ethereum.org/2015/06/26/state-tree-pruning/)

Vitalik says: "but we do not store history older than 5000 blocks.".

1) Is it to be understood that the state Trie does not contain the state of accounts which were not in use during the last 5000 blocks?

2)Let's say a guy awakeness from a hibernation after 50 years and he wants to make a transaction referencing a block which happened years ago. Taking into account all the current blockchain pruning algorithms implemented or to be soon implemented into Ethereum; how would the protocol go about that? I assume most of the typical full nodes wouldn't even contain the blocks containing transactions mentioning that particular account on their HDDs (again are there any blockchain (not the Trie State) pruning algorithms in place right now?) Probably it would be contained on a few of the archival nodes. How would the protocol go about that?

So the question spans a little across the architecture of Ethereum itself (it suggests that we actually do have a few types of full-nodes, ones that store all the data and others who decided to use some pruning algorithms.) Not that it threatens cryptographic security, as the recent hashes would be enough to verify whether those placed 50 years ago are correct but that would require verifying all the blocks again once we deleted them from the state Trie.Other option would be to TRUST an archival node right-away but then not the cryptographic security BUT, the decentralized nature of services suffers greatly.

Curious am I.

Answer (score 1):

1. This is incorrect. I think the disconnect is that the block doesn't just contain changes to the state, it also contains the state root itself, which is generated using the entire current state. Essentially this means that, for the last 5000 blocks, the *entire* state is stored for each of those blocks, but discarded for blocks before that. So you have the state of every account at blocks n to n-5000, but not before that.
2. Again, see #1. The person wouldn't have issues because their account would still exist in the current state. Not quite sure what you mean by "referencing a block which happened years ago" though. You don't  reference a block when making a transaction. They may be confused though since in 10 years the Ethereum blockchain will likely look pretty different with sharding, plasma, casper, etc.

Comment: I know that each block contains a state root. Blocks contain transactions which alter/update the current state. That's clear.

Comment: I think what you wrote is to a large extent wrong. It suggests Ethereum stores the entire copy of a trie for each of the past 5000 blocks, whereas the Vitalik's blogs and logic suggest non-modified nodes are simply referenced in the new instance of the Trie.

Comment: My only trouble is; how does network process a transaction which references an account whose state is no longer part of the State Trie. As I understand after 5000 blocks it is no longer part of the State Trie has been pruned and now it needs to be recalculated from the transaction history. Wrong?

Comment: It doesn't need to store an entire copy of the state trie for each of the 5000 blocks. Much of the data is unchanged, so it doesn't re-store it. But the state root is the merkle patricia tree of the entire state. It still stores the complete state of the last 5000 blocks, even though much of it is unchanged in those blocks and references the oldest block that the state is still stored for. It isn't actually a reference to the old block.

Comment: For example: a contract that is unchanged from block 1 to block 2 and to block 3 will have the same hash, so the state of that contract is only stored once in the database, and lookups of the hashes all point to the same data.

Comment: Again, this doesn't mean that data that hasn't changed in the last 5000 blocks is pruned. It just means that outdated states (e.g. the balance of your address 6000 blocks ago that has a different balance now) are discarded.

Comment: Let's say that we've got a very large state Trie.Now. During the next 5000 blocks, we make transactions just between two accounts. The algorithm keeps updating the account's balances (adding new nodes to the state trie which reference the parent nodes of the past states of the two accounts). This goes on for 5000blocks. Now. After we have more than 5000 blocks the pruning kicks in. The majority of the state Trie is now in the 5001st block. are all of those states deleted?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're saying. The state in the current block is always the current state of the entire system. It doesn't contain outdated states, only the most updated states of the accounts. The states of accounts at n-5001 are only stored in the database if they're still relevant, e.g. if the state of the account is still accurate. If it's no longer accurate, then it's pruned.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help. Actually, my sample and question were very specific. https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/pull/2111  We haven't mentioned that the initial Vitalik's proposal incorporated counting to resolve problems such as this AND most importantly that the described algorithm never made it be implemented. Any ideas what are the current prunning algos then?